# 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice' and more, python calculator

Tags: python

Answers.py

```
import Input
import Start
import Multiplications


if input.choice == "1":
    print(input.num1, "+", input.num2, "+", Multiplications.Add(input.num1, input.num2))

elif input.choice == "2":
    print(input.num1, "-", input.num2, "=", Multiplications.Subtract(input.num1, input.num2))

elif input.choice == "3":
    print(input.num1, "*", input.num2, "=", Multiplications.Multiply(input.num1, input.num2))

elif input.choice == "4":
    print(input.num1, "/", input.num2, "=", Multiplications.Divide(input.num1, input.num2))
```

Input.py

```
def operation():   
  choice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4: ")
  #Check if the input is one of the four options
  if choice in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
```

Main.py

```
import Input
import Answers
import Multiplications
import Start

Start.operations()
Input.operation()
```

Multiplications.py

```
#This function adds two numbers
def Add(x, y):
    return x + y

#This function subtracts two numbers
def Subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

#This function multiplies two numbers
def Multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

#This function divides two numbers
def Divide(x, y):
    return x / y
```

Start.py

```
import time

def operations():
 print("Select Operation: ")
 time.sleep(1)
 print("1) Add")
 time.sleep(1)
 print("2) Subtract")
 time.sleep(1)
 print("3) Multiply")
 time.sleep(1)
 print("4) Divide")
```

i get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Coding\Microsoft VS Code\CODES\Projects\Whole Numbers Calculator (simple)\Main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Answers
  File "f:\Coding\Microsoft VS Code\CODES\Projects\Whole Numbers Calculator (simple)\Answers.py", line 6, in <module>
    if input.choice == "1":
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

i am doing it in diffrent files so it will look more clean

i tried everything but i cant fix it, the error is in the import i think because the input.choise seems to be the problem, any help appreciated ty!

Comment: 1. Case matters in Python so `Input` is not the same as `input`.
2. `choice` is a variable inside the `operation` so it is not accessible outside of that method.

Comment: `input` is a built-in function

Comment: While I am uncertain if the following will completely correct your problem it certainly is a contributor.  Since the term 'input' is a builtin python function, don't name one of your file 'input.py'  try changing this file name to something other than input.py, update you import statement to import the new fille and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @DMalan It worked but now there is an error "module 'Start' has no attribute 'operation'

Comment: This is subjective, but with something like this, I think it would look a lot cleaner to be written as a single file. It would certainly be a lot easier to write, read, and debug as a single .py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

Answers.py

```
import Multiplications
import Input
Input.operation()
if Input.choice == "1":
    print(Input.num1, "+", Input.num2, "+", Multiplications.Add(Input.num1, Input.num2))

elif Input.choice == "2":
    print(Input.num1, "-", Input.num2, "=", Multiplications.Subtract(Input.num1, Input.num2))

elif Input.choice == "3":
    print(Input.num1, "*", Input.num2, "=", Multiplications.Multiply(Input.num1, Input.num2))

elif Input.choice == "4":
    print(Input.num1, "/", Input.num2, "=", Multiplications.Divide(Input.num1, Input.num2))
```

Input.py

```
def operation():   
  global choice
  choice = input("Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4: ")
  #Check if the input is one of the four options
  if choice in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
    global num1,num2
    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
```

Main.py(Optimized)

```
import Start
Start.operations()
import Answers
```

Start.py

```
import time

def operations():
 print("Select Operation: ")
 time.sleep(1)
 print("1) Add")
 time.sleep(1)
 print("2) Subtract")
 time.sleep(1)
 print("3) Multiply")
 time.sleep(1)
 print("4) Divide")
```

Comment: the problem was that choice was inside operation so i needed to do Input.operation but after i fixed this there is another error "module 'Start' has no attribute 'operations"

Comment: ok i will fix this

Comment: Thank you! you are a saver man

Comment: fixed:  i'm glad to help,

Comment: also, you should click on the ✅ icon, so it checks as an answer to your problem.
You're welcome